# Using Rails / Node.js / Scala as an API for a hybrid mobile app serving real-time updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, google-maps, scala, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm building a location-based app that needs to provide users with real-time information about the location of people nearby.  I'm looking to avoid building native iOS + Android apps by using a service like [Trigger.io](http://trigger.io/) to build a hybrid version with Google Maps + Javascript/HTML/CSS that can serve real-time information via a central back-end API.

I am most comfortable in Rails, but I'm wondering what kind of performance lag I will have with Rails for serving real-time updates compared to using a more powerful concurrency-ready back-end system like Node.js or Scala (with Akka) for the API.

In particular, how do Rails/Node.js/Scala (with Akka) differ in serving real-time information within a hybrid mobile app?  To avoid this becoming a subjective debate, I'm most interested in seeing measured performance numbers for a task similar to what I've described. Any links to helpful tools that help improve the ability of either Rails/Node.js/Scala to handle real-time updating within a hybrid mobile map environment would also be appreciated.

Comment: Hey, we're creating a very similar app and we're at the same point you describe: if we should use rails or node or another technology. Did you arrive to any conclusion? Thanks for the info!

Comment: My question on Quora received some answers that may help: https://www.quora.com/For-a-hybrid-mobile-app-serving-real-time-updates-can-I-use-Ruby-on-Rails-for-the-API-or-do-I-need-a-more-powerful-concurrency-ready-back-end-system-like-Node-js-or-Scala-with-Akka

I can't give you a good answer except to say that if real-time updates is a large component of what you're doing, Rails is not a good choice.  Look into Node.js/Scala/Erlang or Go instead.